# How to sum values in dictionary based on position?

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, key-value

I have a dictionary that for each key there are five values in list, such as:

```
{"A": [0, 0.12, 0, 0.73, 0], "B": [0.96, 0, 0.30, 0, 0],
  "C": [0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0],    "D": [0, 0.07, 0, 0.42, 0]}
```

I want to sum first, second and etc. values for all keys and add it in new list such as:

```
[0.96, 0.19, 0.3, 1.26, 0]
```

I tried by below code solve it but It didn't work:

```
aa = {"A": [0, 0.12, 0, 0.73, 0], "B": [0.96, 0, 0.30, 0, 0], "C": [0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0], "D": [0, 0.07, 0, 0.42, 0]}
bb = []
for value in (aa.items()):
    for item in value:
        bb.append(item)
```

Comment: what do you mean "didn't work"? what error did you get?

Comment: `dict.items()` returns generator of key-value `tuple`s, if you need to iterate through values use `dict.values()`

Comment: Hi @honi, the result is : `['A', [0, 0.12, 0, 0.73, 0], 'C', [0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0], 'B', [0.96, 0, 0.3, 0, 0], 'D', [0, 0.07, 0, 0.42, 0]]`

Comment: Hi @Azat Ibrakov, the result for `dict.values()` is : `[0, 0.12, 0, 0.73, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0, 0.96, 0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0.07, 0, 0.42, 0]`

Comment: @nickan, `dict.values()` should be a list of lists (Py2) not a flat list of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `zip()` function

```
aa = {"A": [0, 0.12, 0, 0.73, 0], "B": [0.96, 0, 0.30, 0, 0], "C": [0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0], "D": [0, 0.07, 0, 0.42, 0]}
bb = []

for value in (zip(*list(aa.values()))):
           bb.append(sum(value))


print (bb)
```

output :

```
 [0.96, 0.19, 0.3, 1.26, 0]
```

Comment: Or more simply: `bb = [sum(value) for value in zip(*aa.values())]`

Answer (score 1):

do you mind using numpy?
if not you can use this

```
aa = {"A": [0, 0.12, 0, 0.73, 0], "B": [0.96, 0, 0.30, 0, 0], "C": [0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0],  "D": [0, 0.07, 0, 0.42, 0]}

import numpy as np
bb = np.array([aa.get(a) for a in aa])
print(np.sum(bb, axis=0))
```

the output will be : [ 0.96  0.19  0.3   1.26  0.  ]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` in addition with `zip` to calculate sum by element wise.

```
from functools import reduce

a = {"A": [0, 0.12, 0, 0.73, 0], "B": [0.96, 0, 0.30, 0, 0],
  "C": [0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0],    "D": [0, 0.07, 0, 0.42, 0]}

b = reduce(lambda x, y: ([x1 + y1 for x1,y1 in zip(x,y)]), a.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try more simple way :

```
>>> aa = {"A": [0, 0.12, 0, 0.73, 0], "B": [0.96, 0, 0.30, 0, 0], "C": [0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0], "D": [0, 0.07, 0, 0.42, 0]}
>>> b = [sum(value) for value in zip(*aa.values())]
>>> b
[0.96, 0.19, 0.3, 1.26, 0]
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you want to use `aa.values()`, not `aa.items()`.  `aa.items` gives tuples of (key, value), but you just want the values.

Second of all, you want to sum the items in the list, so use sum.

```
aa = {"A": [0, 0.12, 0, 0.73, 0], "B": [0.96, 0, 0.30, 0, 0], "C": [0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0], "D": [0, 0.07, 0, 0.42, 0]}
bb = []
for value in (aa.values()):
        bb.append(sum(value))
```

Comment: result for your code is : [0.85, 0.11, 1.26, 0.49], that it is incorrect.

Comment: ah, i misunderstood your question.