# How to divide list values in a dictionary to another list?

Tags: python, dictionary

In a dictionary with multiple values in list for each key,

```
aa = {"A": [0, 0.12, 0, 0.73, 0], "B": [0.96, 0, 0.30, 0, 0], "C": [0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0], "D": [0, 0.07, 0, 0.42, 0]}
```

after obtain sum all values in arrangement for all keys based on answers to [How to sum values in dictionary based on position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407538/how-to-sum-values-in-dictionary-based-on-position)

```
bb = [sum(value) for value in zip(*aa.values())]
```

result for `bb` is `[0.96, 0.19, 0.3, 1.26, 0]`.

I want to divide values in each key to bb, that result must be:

```
{"A": [0, 0.63, 0, 0.57, 0], "B": [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], "C": [0, 0, 0, 0.087, 0], "D": [0, 0.36, 0, 0.33, 0]}
```

I tried by this code:

```
aa = {"A": [0, 0.12, 0, 0.73, 0], "B": [0.96, 0, 0.30, 0, 0], "C": [0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0], "D": [0, 0.07, 0, 0.42, 0]}
bb = [sum(value) for value in zip(*aa.values())]

cc = {}
for key, value in (aa.items()):
    cc.setdefault(key, [])
    cc[key].append((x*1.0)/y for x, y in zip(aa, bb))
```

but its result is not correct.

```
{'A': [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f998d0640f0>], 'C': [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f998d064140>], 'B': [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f998d0640a0>], 'D': [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f998d064050>]}
```

Comment: Your code and unexpected output do **not match**. That'd indicate you used `append()` and not `extend()`.

Comment: Why are you re-posting the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408275/how-to-divide-values-in-a-dictionary-to-sum-of-values ?

Comment: Hi @  Ashwini Chaudhary, sorry I am new in stackoverflow and I couldn't explain completely for that post so deleted it and reposted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension on each list value; no need to use `dict.setdefault()` here, and do use `value` (one of the lists), not `aa` (the whole dictionary), as the input for `zip()`:

```
cc = {}
for key, value in aa.items():
    cc[key] = [0.0 if not y else ((x * 1.0) / y) for x, y in zip(value, bb)]
```

You do need to test for `y == 0.0` to avoid division-by-0 errors.

You can use a dictionary comprehension here too:

```
cc = {key: [0.0 if not y else ((x * 1.0) / y) for x, y in zip(value, bb)]
      for key, value in aa.items()}
```

Demo:

```
>>> {key: [0.0 if not y else ((x * 1.0) / y) for x, y in zip(value, bb)] for key, value in aa.items()}
{'A': [0.0, 0.631578947368421, 0.0, 0.5793650793650793, 0.0], 'C': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0873015873015873, 0.0], 'B': [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'D': [0.0, 0.368421052631579, 0.0, 0.3333333333333333, 0.0]}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you need computation like this, better using numpy
the code will be much easire to read and intrepet, no need to use looping at all

```
import numpy as np

aa = {"A": [0, 0.12, 0, 0.73, 0], "B": [0.96, 0, 0.30, 0, 0], "C": [0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0], "D": [0, 0.07, 0, 0.42, 0]}

aa = np.array([aa.get(a) for a in aa])

//or any bb you want
bb = np.array([2,2,2,2])
print((aa.T/bb).T)
```

Comment: Hi @Po Stevanus Andrianta, I received error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: something wrong with that @nickan 
aa is a dict not a list
please check it here https://repl.it/Jrb6/0